# How to write a javascript function that figures out the angle of two points?

Tags: javascript

Assuming that a straight line pointing north is 0 degrees and goes up to 359.
If given two points each with an x and y value, how do you find out what "angle" it makes between the first point and the second point? Assuming an (arctan2) function exists is okay.

I have the following:

```
    var x = x2 - x1;
    var y = y2 - y1;
    var radian = arctan2(y, x);
    var degrees = radian * 180 / 3.14;
```

I seem to be getting "0 degrees" on the right arrow and 270 pointing north instead of the 0 degrees I am looking for towards the north.

Comment: Assuming you went to class and have a textbook etc., what have you tried?

Comment: Crack open your high school trig textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If coordinate system have 0 degrees pointing up/north x comes first for the atan2 function:

```
var x = x2 - x1;
var y = y2 - y1;
var angleDegrees = Math.atan2(x, y) * 180 / Math.PI;

if (angleDegrees < 0) angleDegrees += 360;  // force positive value
```

Comment: There is a restriction in his question he set a range of 0 - 360 degrees, and I get negative angles with your solution.

Comment: He was explicit so it was a requirement. +1